# Get type of object as simple class name

Tags: python-3.x

When I use the type function, it returns me:

```
>>>print(type('string'))
<class 'str'>

class Test:
    pass
test_obj = Test()
>>>print(type(test_obj))
<class '__main__.Test'>
```

I'm just wondering whether it is possible for it to output `str` and `Test` only instead of 
`'<class 'str'>'` or `<class '__main__.Test'>`

Comment: Oh damn, it worked. Thanks for the answer Infinity.